# Raspberry pi issues updating json file

Tags: php, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I've created a website that updates a json file based on users inputs.

 I developed this on my windows pc, tested the site running WAMP and it works correctly. 
I wanted to put this on my raspberry pi, its running apache2 and php5. I've placed the website in /var/www/html/ the website loads correctly and functions. With the exception of changing settings on the page, the json file is never updated.

This is the php file:

```
<?php
$LightOne = $_POST['lightOne'];
$LightTwo = $_POST['lightTwo'];
$LightThree = $_POST['lightThree'];

$ActivateLightsJson = file_get_contents('json/ActivateLights.json');
$ActivateLights = json_decode($ActivateLightsJson, true);

$ActivateLights["lightOne"] = $LightOne;
$ActivateLights["lightTwo"] = $LightTwo;
$ActivateLights["lightThree"] = $LightThree;

$fp = fopen('json/ActivateLights.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($ActivateLights));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The js that calls the php:

```
function saveJson(){
lightOne = document.getElementById("lightOne").checked ? 1 : 0;
lightTwo = document.getElementById("lightTwo").checked ? 1 : 0;
lightThree = document.getElementById("lightThree").checked ? 1 : 0; 
$.post('saveJson.php',{lightOne:lightOne, lightTwo:lightTwo, lightThree:lightThree}, function(data){});
}
```

I updated permission to /www using 
`sudo chown $logname /var/www/` unfortunately that did not work. 

 Any advice?

Comment: What are the permissions you see on the directory ***and the file*** in a `ls -l`? There's nothing wrong with that code, so the problem has to lie somewhere else.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple - I'm sorry if I sniped your potential answer here.  I didn't notice your comment until after I submitted my potential answer.  I can delete if you'd like to post once you get the appropriate data from your question.

Comment: the permission on the json file is 
total 4
-rw-r---r-- 1 pi pi 48 data.json

Comment: Also, in the comment above, you mention the file is named "data.json", but in your code it is named "ActivateLights.json".  The file name in the /var/www/html/json directory needs to be ActiveLights.json (case-sensitive) to match your code and must be owned by 'www-data' using the commands below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is still a permissions error.

The 'json' directory and the file itself must be owned by the apache user or world writeable (generally considered less desirable).  The command you issued was not recursive so it did not change the appropriate files.  Additionally, $LOGNAME (case-sensitive) is the currently logged in user and not the Apache process which is probably something like 'www-data' depending on your linux distribution.

So, you probably need something like:

sudo chown -R www-data json

This would allow the apache process to write to your JSON file and it's parent (json) directory assuming you ran it from the '/var/www/html' directory.

Comment: my site in in /var/www/html/ the folder is in the json folder in the html folder /var/www/html/json when I run the command you provided it says 'chown cannot access 'json': no such file or directory'. Sorry I'm new to linux commands

Comment: Try it from the /var/www/html directory - you just need to run it in the folder that contains the "json" directory.  If you need to get to that directory, you can "cd /var/www/html" or you could run the command as "sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/json" which will change the permissions no matter where you run it from because it references the whole path.

Comment: Thank you, you sent me in the right direction. ended up just running chmod 777 Data.json not really secure but its just for a personal project so its okay. Thank you again.